# Java not detecting file contents

Tags: java, newline

I'm having difficulty figuring out why this isn't working. Java simply isn't executing the while loop, file apparently does not have a next line.

```
fileName = getFileName(keyboard);
file = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
pass = true;
String currentLine;
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    currentLine = file.nextLine();
    System.out.println(reverse(currentLine));
}
```

Here is the file I am testing this with. I got it to work with the first few paragraphs but it seems to simply stop working...:

Jabberwocky

'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

"Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!"

He took his vorpal sword in hand:
Long time the manxome foe he soughtó
So rested he by the Tumtum tree,
And stood awhile in thought.

And as in uffish thought he stood,
The Jabberwock, with eyes of flame,
Came whiffling through the tulgey wood,
And burbled as it came!

One, two! One, two! and through and through
The vorpal blade went snicker-snack!
He left it dead, and with its head
He went galumphing back.

"And hast thou slain the Jabberwock?
Come to my arms, my beamish boy!
O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!"
He chortled in his joy.

'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

——from Through the Looking-Glass, and What Alice Found There (1872).

```
/*
 * Lab13a.java
 * 
 *   A program that prompts the user for an input file name and, if that file exists,
 *   displays each line of that file in reverse order.
 *   Used to practice simple File I/O and breaking code up into methods as well as a first
 *   step to implementing Lab13b.java - reversing the entire file and Lab13c.java writing 
 *   output to a separate output file.
 * 
 * @author Benjamin Meyer
 * 
 */
package osu.cse1223;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Lab13a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = "";
        Scanner file;
        boolean pass = false;
        while (!pass) {
            try {
                fileName = getFileName(keyboard);
                file = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
                pass = true;
                String currentLine;
                while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                    currentLine = file.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(reverse(currentLine));
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("There was a problem reading from " + fileName);
                System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    // Given a Scanner as input prompts the user to enter a file name.  If given an
    // empty line, respond with an error message until the user enters a non-empty line.
    // Return the string to the calling program.  Note that this method should NOT try
    // to determine whether the file name is an actual file - it should just get a
    // valid string from the user.
    private static String getFileName(Scanner inScanner) {
        boolean pass = true;
        String fileName = "";
        while (pass) {
            System.out.print("Enter an input name: ");
            fileName = inScanner.nextLine();
            if (fileName.length()!=0) {
                pass = false;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You cannot enter an empty string.");
            }
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    // Given a String as input return the reverse of that String to the calling program.
    private static String reverse(String inString) {
        if (inString.length()==0) {
            return "";
        }
        String reversed = "" + inString.charAt(inString.length()-1);
        for (int x = inString.length()-2; x>=0; x--) {
            reversed = reversed + inString.charAt(x);
        }
        return reversed;
    }


}
```

Comment: You're not showing the full exception stacktrace. In your catch block, at least do `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: It never executes the catch block (or at least it isn't in this case.)

Comment: The code above. Is it your `main()` method?  If not, how do you know that the method it belongs to is really getting called?

Comment: Instead of this `fileName = getFileName(keyboard);` try using this `fileName = keyBoard.nextLine().trim();`.

Comment: Are any of your `System.out.println()`s printing out? If they do, then there IS an exception occuring

Comment: You are going to have to show more code. Also, tell us exactly where in the above sequence it hangs. My guess is that the getFileName() call is never returning. You can check this by hard coding a string for the filename (instead of prompting) and see if it works.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing printing to the console except asking for a filename. It seems to be getting stuck at while(file.hasNextLine()). If I change it to while(!file.hasNextLine()), I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
 at osu.cse1223.Lab13a.main(Lab13a.java:32)

Comment: If I shorted the file to the title and the first paragraph, the program provides this, which is correct: ykcowrebbaJ

sevot yhtils eht dna ,gillirb sawT'
;ebaw eht ni elbmig dna eryg diD
,sevogorob eht erew ysmim llA
.ebargtuo shtar emom eht dnA

Comment: In the file I was putting into the program, it has the character (o with an accent) ó. If I take it out of the file, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might lie in your implementation of your functions getFilename() or reverse(). Since you have stated that you got it to work with a few of the paragraphs I doubt that your program  is failing due to your file handling. It might be in the logic you are using to reverse the strings in the file that is causing the issue.

Comment: It never actually runs the method to reverse the code as the while loop is always false.